# How to pass generic record as parameter to TFileStream.Read function?

Tags: delphi

I have several record types to read from file, for example

```
  PDescriptorBlockHeader = ^TDescriptorBlockHeader;
  TDescriptorBlockHeader = packed record

    BlockType: UInt32;
    BlockAttributes: UInt32; // +4
    OffsetToFirstEvent: UInt16; // +8
    OsId: byte; // +10
    OsVersion: byte;
    DisplayableSize: UInt64;  // +12
    FormatLogicalAddress: UInt64; // +20
    SessionId: UInt64; // +28
    ControlBlockID: UInt32; // +36
    StringStorage: MTF_TAPE_ADDRESS; // +40
    OsSpecificData: MTF_TAPE_ADDRESS; // +44
    StringType: byte; // +48
    Reserved: byte; // +49
    HeaderChecksum: UInt16; //+50
  end;
```

and I want to use common function to read from file

```
type
  TReaderHelper = class
    class procedure ReadToStruct<T:record>(stream: TFileStream; offset: Int64);
  end;

implementation

class procedure TReaderHelper.ReadToStruct<T>(stream: TFileStream; offset: Int64);
var
  rd: integer;
begin
  stream.Position := offset;
  if stream.Position <> offset then
    raise Exception.Create('Seek error');
  rd := stream.Read(T, sizeof(T));
  if rd <> sizeof(T) then
    raise Exception.Create('Read ' + IntToStr(rd) + ' instead of ' + IntToStr(sizeof(T)));
end;
```

Compiler gives me error `E2571 Type parameter 'T' doesn't have class or interface constraint` at `rd := stream.Read(T, sizeof(T));`. Is it possible to pass that generic record as parameter to TFileStream.Read function?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`T` represents a Type, not a variable. You need to pass a variable to `Read()`. Add an output variable to your code and read into it, eg :

```pascal
type
  TReaderHelper = class
    class procedure ReadToStruct<T:record>(stream: TFileStream; offset: Int64: out rec: T);
  end;

implementation

class procedure TReaderHelper.ReadToStruct<T>(stream: TFileStream; offset: Int64; out rec: T);
var
  rd: integer;
begin
  stream.Position := offset;
  if stream.Position <> offset then
    raise Exception.Create('Seek error');
  rd := stream.Read(rec, sizeof(T));
  if rd <> sizeof(T) then
    raise Exception.Create('Read ' + IntToStr(rd) + ' instead of ' + IntToStr(sizeof(T)));
end;
```

Alternatively :

```pascal
type
  TReaderHelper = class
    class function ReadToStruct<T:record>(stream: TFileStream; offset: Int64): T;
  end;

implementation

class function TReaderHelper.ReadToStruct<T>(stream: TFileStream; offset: Int64): T;
var
  rd: integer;
begin
  stream.Position := offset;
  if stream.Position <> offset then
    raise Exception.Create('Seek error');
  rd := stream.Read(Result, sizeof(T));
  if rd <> sizeof(T) then
    raise Exception.Create('Read ' + IntToStr(rd) + ' instead of ' + IntToStr(sizeof(T)));
end;
```

Answer (score 8):

You are trying to read directly to `T` which is the **type**. You need to provide a **variable** of that type into which to read.

```
type
  TReaderHelper = class
    class procedure ReadToStruct<T: record>(stream: TStream; offset: Int64; out Data: T);
  end;

class procedure TReaderHelper.ReadToStruct<T>(stream: TStream; offset: Int64; out Data: T);
begin
  stream.Position := offset;
  stream.ReadBuffer(Data, sizeof(T));
end;
```

Rather than supply a specific stream class like `TFileStream`, it is more flexible to supply a generic stream class. This allows you to use this method with different stream implementations.

The seek exception that you raised serves no purpose because it is possible to seek beyond the end of a file. Any errors arise in subsequent read or write actions.

The other exception is fine, but it is perhaps simpler to use `ReadBuffer` and let the stream class raise an exception in case the requested amount of data cannot be read.